# How to run single test method in android instrumented test class and how to change edit configuration for this

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have written multiple test methods in a single android instrumented test class, when I am trying to run a single test method it will run all methods exists in that class.
I want to run only one.

Earlier I was able to run all, but somehow configuration settings have been changed

```
class HistoryTest{

@Test
fun openHistoryTest{
}

@Test
fun closeHistoryTest{
}

@Test
fun editHistoryTest{
}
}
```

I want to run a specific single test method say openHistoryTest.
Currently getting an error - the command line is too long shorten the command line for test "testname"

Comment: nobody replied :(

Comment: Have the same problem. I can't run just one single test method. Must be an Android Studio problem and didn't find any solution.

Comment: Might be some android studio problem, because when I update the android studio to the new version then only I started getting this issue otherwise earlier I WAS happy in running single as well as a complete test case class. One thing i found weird is - suppose I have ten test classes out of those in ONE class I am still able to run single test method, don't know how it will automatically add the test method or class in config settings.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Android Studio to canary and can run the whole class or a single method as instrumental test. Currently using AS 3.6 Canary 12.

Still doesn't work on Android Studio 3.5. I can't run each method as an 
instrumental test, only the whole class.

Comment: can you provide some info on how to update to this version AS 3.6 Canary 12

Comment: You will have 2 different AS apps. Here's the page for download. developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html